# XCode crash caused storyboard to disappear

Tags: ios, xcode

After my XCode crashed my main.storyboard file is red with a D next to it. When I try to build my project it fails and gives me the error "Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler Error: Interface Builder could not open the document Main.storyboard because it does not exist" When I go to my Base.lproj the file is no longer there. I didn't delete my storyboard can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?? I'm on Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: Is the file exist? I mean, on your disk?

Answer (score 1):

'D' button in xcode probably means that your project is under some kind of version control system. In that case you can simply revert the changes to your file from xcode. Right-click on the deleted file and choose "Source Control -> Discard changes to ..." in menu

You can also discard changes to your file from terminal using the following command:

```
git checkout -- file
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can add it in you project by right clicking any file and `add
  files to "project name"` instead of `New File`, it will open Finder ,
  where your project resources are included. Check for the file named
  Main.StoryBoard and click open.
- Incase you have deleted (Accidentally) open trash and check if it is
  present there. Right click it and check **Put Back** and do the above
  procedure.